# How to convert specific column value as header for set of values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

tableA

```
 +-----------+--------+--------------+
  | tableA_id |  code  | Department   |
  +-----------+--------+--------------+
  |         1 | code A | Science 1    |
  |         2 | code B | Science 1    |
  |         3 | code A | Science 2    |
  |         4 | code C | Science 1    |
  |         5 | code B | Science 2    |
  |         6 | code A | Science 3    | 
  |         7 | code C | Science 2    |
  |         8 | code B | Science 3    |
  |         9 | code A | Science 4    |
  |        10 | code C | Science 3    |
  |        11 | code B | Science 4    |
  +-----------+--------+--------------+
```

I want to convert it using SQL query in below format

```
 +--------------+ 
 | Department   |
 +--------------+
 |  Code A      |
 +--------------+
 |  Science 1   |
 |  Science 2   |
 |  Science 3   |
 |  Science 4   |
 +--------------+ 
 |  Code  B     |
 +--------------+
 | Science 1    |
 | Science 2    |
 | Science 3    |
 | Science 4    |
 +--------------+
 |  Code C      |
 +--------------+
 | Science 1    |
 | Science 2    |
 | Science 3    |
 +--------------+
```

Basically i want it group by Code but need to display Code at top of each group and values in column not fixed it comes dynamically.

Comment: This is a Really bad pattern to adopt for SQL.  You should consider generating results in SQL that make sense in SQL, then having a transformation layer in your application.  I would not allow this through a code review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with a [group by rollup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql).

### Initial solution

```
-- create sample data
declare @data table
(
    id int,
    code nvarchar(10),
    department nvarchar(20)
);

insert into @data (id, code, department) values
( 1, 'code A', 'Science 1'),
( 2, 'code B', 'Science 1'),
( 3, 'code A', 'Science 2'),
( 4, 'code C', 'Science 1'),
( 5, 'code B', 'Science 2'),
( 6, 'code A', 'Science 3'),
( 7, 'code C', 'Science 2'),
( 8, 'code B', 'Science 3'),
( 9, 'code A', 'Science 4'),
(10, 'code C', 'Science 3'),
(11, 'code B', 'Science 4');
```

Single result query:

```
-- solution
select coalesce(d.department, d.code) as 'Department'
from @data d
group by d.code, d.department with rollup
having grouping(d.code) = 0
order by d.code, d.department;
```

Run this query to understand how I came to the previous solution:

```
-- solution explained
select  grouping(d.department) as 'grouping_dep',
        d.department,
        grouping(d.code) as 'grouping_cod',
        d.code,
        coalesce(d.department, d.code) as 'Department',
        case
            when grouping(d.code) = 1 then 'aggregation across codes, filtered out with "having"'
            else 'select "department", replace with "code" when null'
        end as 'explanation'
from @data d
group by d.code, d.department with rollup -- group on every level and "roll up" the aggregations
order by d.code, d.department;
```

### Expanded solution

Handles 2 extra columns (based on additional input in comment).

```
-- create sample data
declare @data table
(
    id int,
    code nvarchar(10),
    department nvarchar(20),
    colA nvarchar(10),
    colB nvarchar(10)
);

insert into @data (id, code, department, colA, colB) values
( 1, 'code A', 'Science 1', 'A1_A', 'A1_B'),
( 2, 'code B', 'Science 1', 'B1_A', 'B1_B'),
( 3, 'code A', 'Science 2', 'A2_A', 'A2_B'),
( 4, 'code C', 'Science 1', 'C1_A', 'C1_B'),
( 5, 'code B', 'Science 2', 'B2_A', 'B2_B'),
( 6, 'code A', 'Science 3', 'A3_A', 'A3_B'),
( 7, 'code C', 'Science 2', 'C2_A', 'C2_B'),
( 8, 'code B', 'Science 3', 'B3_A', 'B3_B'),
( 9, 'code A', 'Science 4', 'A4_A', 'A4_B'),
(10, 'code C', 'Science 3', 'C3_A', 'C3_B'),
(11, 'code B', 'Science 4', 'B4_A', 'B4_B');
```

Because of the grouping you will need to use an aggregation function (like the `min` function use here) to select the values.

```
-- solution
select  coalesce(d.department, d.code) as 'Department',
        case when grouping(d.department)=1 then '' else min(d.colA) end as 'colA',
        case when grouping(d.department)=1 then '' else min(d.colB) end as 'colB'
from @data d
group by d.code, d.department with rollup
having grouping(d.code) = 0
order by d.code, d.department;
```

This gives:

```
Department           colA       colB
-------------------- ---------- ----------
code A
Science 1            A1_A       A1_B
Science 2            A2_A       A2_B
Science 3            A3_A       A3_B
Science 4            A4_A       A4_B
code B
Science 1            B1_A       B1_B
Science 2            B2_A       B2_B
Science 3            B3_A       B3_B
Science 4            B4_A       B4_B
code C
Science 1            C1_A       C1_B
Science 2            C2_A       C2_B
Science 3            C3_A       C3_B
```

Comment: What if i have 3 additional column in table?

Comment: I updated my solution with 2 extra columns. You can accept my answer if this completes your question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a presentation layer task. One way is to use `cursor` to select distinct codes and sequentially add records into the final table as per the codes.

```
 DECLARE @final TABLE (Department varchar(100))
 DECLARE @code varchar(10)

 DECLARE cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR 
 SELECT DISTINCT code FROM @t t 

 OPEN cur
 FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @code

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @final SELECT @code 
    INSERT INTO @final 
    SELECT Department FROM @t t
    WHERE t.code = @code    

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @code  
 END

 CLOSE cur
 DEALLOCATE cur

 SELECT * FROM @final f
```

Please find the demo **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9b5b2485b8dab07cbbedd517b21b7274)** (includes additional columns too).

Comment: What if i have 3 additional column in table?

Comment: @Bhushan can you please add an example of that....also the expected output?